# Python generics: how to create object of an appropriate class?

Tags: python, oop

I have the following code (this code is just for testing):

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type
import abc


class BaseMultiplier(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def multiply(self, n):
        pass


class MultiplierByTwo(BaseMultiplier):
    def multiply(self, n):
        return n * 2


class MultiplierByThree(BaseMultiplier):
    def multiply(self, n):
        return n * 3


Multiplier = TypeVar('Multiplier', Type[MultiplierByTwo], Type[MultiplierByThree])


class MultiplierCreator(Generic[Multiplier]):
    def create(self) -> Multiplier:
        # I need to create an instance of Multiplier here
        pass


class MultiplierByTwoCreator(MultiplierCreator[MultiplierByTwo]):
    pass


class MultiplierByThreeCreator(MultiplierCreator[MultiplierByThree]):
    pass
```

So how can I create an instance of an appropriate `Multiplier` class in `create` method?
So the following code must not raise any exceptions:

```py
creator_by_two = MultiplierByTwoCreator()
assert type(creator_by_two.create()) == MultiplierByTwo

creator_by_three = MultiplierByThreeCreator()
assert type(creator_by_three.create()) == MultiplierByThree
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MultiplierCreator(Generic[Multiplier]):
    def create(self) -> Multiplier:
        return self.multiplier()


class MultiplierByTwoCreator(MultiplierCreator[MultiplierByTwo]):
    multiplier = MultiplierByTwo


class MultiplierByThreeCreator(MultiplierCreator[MultiplierByThree]):
    multiplier = MultiplierByThree
```

By adding class attributes to the subclasses of `MultiplierCreator` that contain the related `Multiplier` subclass you can then use the inherited method `create()` to call this class attributes and return an instance of it. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Aside from that, to check whether an object is of the correct type you may want to use `isinstance()`:

```
assert isinstance(creator_by_two.create(), MultiplierByTwo)
assert isinstance(creator_by_three.create(), MultiplierByThree)
```

Hopefully this can help you.

Comment: Yes, now I use a property containing an appropriate class. But I thought using generics would let me get rid of redeclaring methods in every child class.